# Using a PLSQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I am trying to use a case statement to determine which select statement should be executed. 
I want to check the third character of the variable `:SSN`. If the third character is a dash, use the first SQL statement to mask the first 5 numbers (`XX-XXX1234`). Otherwise, use the second SQL statement to mask the first 5 numbers (`XXX-XX-1234`).

What is the correct syntax for this?

```
select case
    when substr(:SSN, 3,1) = '-' then
    SELECT 'XX-XXX'||substr(:SSN, 7,4) INTO :MaskedSSN FROM DUAL
else
    SELECT 'XXX-XX-'||substr(:SSN, 8,4) INTO :MaskedSSN FROM DUAL
end
```

Comment: If you're in PL/SQL and not just in an SQL query, why not using a simple IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL `CASE` *expression* for this

```
select case
    when substr(:SSN, 3,1) = '-' then
     'XX-XXX'||substr(:SSN, 7,4)  
else
     'XXX-XX-'||substr(:SSN, 8,4) 
end
INTO :MaskedSSN
from dual
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the code used:
        select case
        when substr(:SSN, 3,1) = '-' then
         'XX-XXX'||substr(:SSN, 7,4)  
    else
        'XXX-XX-'||substr(:SSN, 8,4) 
    end
    INTO :MaskedSSN
    from dual

Comment: But keep in mind that @AndreaBergia gave good advice. It is a small overhead to use SQL in pl\sql for this task.

Answer (score 0):

> Just an alternaive to try.Enjoy

```
SELECT DECODE(SUBSTR(:SSN, 3,1),'-','XX-XXX'
  ||SUBSTR(:SSN, 7,4),'XXX-XX-'
  ||SUBSTR(:SSN, 8,4))
INTO lv_var
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Useless use of SQL context (i.e. `select from dual`) in PL/SQL is a very poor practise. Here we have a perfectly valid and simple PL/SQL only solution (this is a PL/SQL question anyway):

```
declare
  function mask_ssn(p_ssn in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  begin
    -- the OP explicitly asked for case-statement even old boring if-statement
    -- would do
    return case 
      when substr(p_ssn, 3, 1) = '-' then 'XX-XXX'  || substr(p_ssn, 7, 4)
      else                                'XXX-XX-' || substr(p_ssn, 8, 4)
    end;
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('masked: ' || mask_ssn('AB-CDE1234'));
  dbms_output.put_line('masked: ' || mask_ssn('ABC-CD-1234'));
end;
/
```

Output:

```
masked: XX-XXX1234
masked: XXX-XX-1234
```

(Note that I said *useless* use - there is many valid use scenarios, but this is not one of them.)